# Why does Jekyll not show an image that's linked to a Google Map?

Tags: html, google-maps, jekyll

Using Jekyll, I was trying to prevent a Google Maps link from 
loading each time by replacing it with a "clickable" image, so that the 
map would only load "on demand" when clicked; I thought that was smart, 
but it doesn't work :-( Would anybody see what's wrong and help me out?

https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=-1.501633,29.631358&z=12&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=RW&mapclient=embed&cid=17550833976507367943

Took a screenshot of the "embedded" map, cropped that, and created a 
link to that image (assets/google_maps.png) in the README.md like this:

`<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=-1.501633,29.631358&z=12&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=RW&mapclient=embed&cid=17550833976507367943"><img src="/assets/google_maps.png" alt="" width="288" height="184" /></a>`

This works fine locally at 127.0.0.1/4000 but having git pushed it, the 
image only shows here:
https://github.com/veteranssafaris/veteranssafaris/blob/master/README.md

and not here:
https://veteranssafaris.github.io/veteranssafaris/

and I can't figure out what's wrong.

The image is located here:
https://github.com/veteranssafaris/veteranssafaris/blob/master/assets/google_maps.png

I googled around and had so many unspecific results, and though I read 
many of them, I don't manage to understand this.

Can anybody please tell me what I am missing here? Is there a way to 
prevent Google maps (or some other such link) to load *each time* by 
linking it to a (low res) clickable image file of itself, to save some 
bandwidth/CO2, and only load it *on demand*?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no image at: https://veteranssafaris.github.io/assets/google_maps.png

Comment: You're right, there isn't. But the link I provided was here: https://github.com/veteranssafaris/veteranssafaris/blob/master/assets/google_maps.png but you used https://veteranssafaris.github.io/assets/google_maps.png Just thought it was only accessible when logged in at github but no, I logged out and can access the image. Please try again!

Comment: It's working! See marcanuy's comment. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your webpage url is: https://veteranssafaris.github.io/veteranssafaris/

So your website is located under `veteranssafaris` and you have to generate links having that in mind:

```
<img src="/veteranssafaris/assets/google_maps.png">
```

In Jekyll, addd the subpath to `_config.yml`:

```
baseurl: /veteranssafaris
```

Then make sure you use that when generating links:

```
<img src="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/google_maps.png">
```

Comment: Works! Thanks! Can I add a question though? The local URL changed to 127.0.0.1:4000/{{ site.baseurl }}; I thought that that was going to happen, but does that change in _config.yml have any other consequences (other than the nice fact that the website displays properly now) when tinkering around?